Unpivot Dataframe with multilayered headers into long format
I have an excel file which has a pivoted table. I want to bring it into a long format so the same can be inserted into a DB.

loading the file in df.
file_path = '/content/drive/My Drive/Experiment_unpivot.xlsx' df = pd.read_excel(file_path,header=[0,1])
df the columns are merged in the excel file so getting
Unnamed: 0_level_0  2023-09-01 00:00:00
Please advise what needs to be done. Using pd.melt or using power query.
I want the melted table

Data has repeated columns under the same month header.

Your data in general makes no sense because it has the same column names twice under each month.  However, here is sample code for Powerquery
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
#"Removed Top Rows" = Table.Skip(Source,1),
#"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Removed Top Rows"),
GetMonthNames = Table.FromColumns({Record.FieldValues(Source{0})}),
#"Filled Down" = Table.ToColumns(Table.FillDown(GetMonthNames,{"Column1"})){0},
NewColumnNames_Part1 = List.Zip ({#"Filled Down",Table.ColumnNames(#"Promoted Headers")}),
NewColumnNames_Part2 = List.Transform(NewColumnNames_Part1, each Text.Combine(_,"-")),
#"Rename Columns"=Table.RenameColumns(Source,List.Zip({Table.ColumnNames(Source),NewColumnNames_Part2}))  ,
#"Removed Two Rows" = Table.Skip(#"Rename Columns",2),
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Removed Two Rows", {"Products"}, "Attribute", "Value")
in #"Unpivoted Other Columns"

You can right-click the Attribute column and split on - character if you want


Thanks @horseyride I was able to do this in power query editor. was not very complicated. want to replicate this thing on pandas DF

Then I have no idea why you tagged the question to powerquery,  but ok
